# Division of two values returning 0 rather than positive or negative decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a large stored procedure updating a table each night. It grabs a basic amount of information in to a temp table before updating each of the remaining columns through a series of updates.

One of these updates is a division. The division takes two previously updated fields and divides them.

```
UPDATE C
SET C.RETURN_ON_SALES = C.TW_UNIT_SALES / C.DISTRIBUTION
FROM
    #custTop150 C
```

The column definitions in #custTop150 are as follows:

```
RETURN_ON_SALES DECIMAL(5,2) NULL
TW_UNIT_SALES INT NULL
[DISTRIBUTION] INT NULL
```

All of my results for this update are returning as 0.00. To give you an example of some of the divisions it is calculating:

```
7 / 41   | Returns 0.00 when it should return 0.17073170731
11 / 41  | Returns 0.00 when it should return 0.26829268292
9 / 41   | Returns 0.00 when it should return 0.21941219512
5 / 38   | Returns 0.00 when it should return 0.13157894736
```

I know that the answer will be pretty simply or right in front of my eyes but at this point in time I am completely lost as to why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Cast `C.TW_UNIT_SALES` to decimal then divide it with distribution, or just multiply it first with `* 1.00` to convert it to decimal, so ether `(cast(7 as decimal(5,2)) / 41)` or `((7 * 1.00) / 41)`

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (They do integer division in different ways.)

Comment: When you divide two integers, then the result will bei an integer, too. In your case the result 0 is correct, because the decimal part of the result is being cut off, for the result to be an integer.

Comment: @schlonzo - thanks for explaining that to me!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I do know this. Apologies for leaving it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you are working on SQL Server. Then change RETURN_ON_SALES to Decimal(10,10) and CAST the inputs or change its data type to DECIMAL

```
 DECLARE @RETURN_ON_SALES decimal(10,10);
 DECLARE @TW_UNIT_SALES INT ;
 DECLARE @DISTRIBUTION INT ;

 SET @TW_UNIT_SALES=7;
 SET @DISTRIBUTION=41;
 SET @RETURN_ON_SALES=CAST(@TW_UNIT_SALES AS DECIMAL (10,5))/ CAST (@DISTRIBUTION AS DECIMAL(10,5));
 PRINT @RETURN_ON_SALES;
```

Comment: Thank you brother, worked perfectly. Appreciate the response - it was right in front of me!!!

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS**: It seems your columns are defined as `INTEGER` and in the division it should return in `DECIMAL` value so for this we can simply change the one of operand value to `DECIMAL` using `CAST` and it will return the `DECIMAL` value as below

```
DECLARE @first INT = 4, @second INT = 3
SELECT @first/@second -- OUTPUT: 1
SELECT @first/CAST(@second AS DECIMAL(10,5)) -- OUTPUT: 1.33333333333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE C
  SET C.RETURN_ON_SALES = 1.0 * C.TW_UNIT_SALES / C.DISTRIBUTION
FROM
    #custTop150 C
```

Note that the `1.0` will cause a cast to float before assigning to the target variable.

You are not specifying which DBMS so, to make sure it works, you may also try the following (if the previous still does not work):

```
UPDATE C
  SET C.RETURN_ON_SALES = (1.0 * C.TW_UNIT_SALES) / (1.0 * C.DISTRIBUTION)
FROM
    #custTop150 C
```

Comment: As the question asks for a `decimal`, I would include in your answer why you chose a `float` instead.  Also, you should clarify that this invokes implicit data-type conversion using data-type order of precedence, and that the exact behaviour varies across each RDBMS.

Comment: Dear @MatBailie, my answer will **ALWAYS** work regardless of the DBMS and the specific type of the variables used for the calculation. Perhaps the DBMS is SQL Server and the type is `MONEY`... Who knows. Moreover, if the requirement is to get very high precision, I would expect the user to state so. As for `DECIMAL`, it specifies 2 digits of precision and hence, again, my solution will definitely work(!).

Comment: There are many, many, more differences between `FLOAT` and `DECIMAL` than precision and scale, for example a `DECIMAL` can *exactly* represent `1.3` where as a `FLOAT` will give a binary approximation *(`1.3` can't be represent in binary for the same reason that a third can't be represented in decimal)*.  Therefore the ***choice*** that you made to use a different data type from the one mentioned in the OPs title should reasonably be explained.

Comment: As for the assertion that it will always work, don't bet on it.  Data-type order of precedence is not part of ANSI-SQL and so the implicit conversion can behave in any manner as defined by the particular RDBMS.  It is indeed *more* normal to implicitly convert to a `FLOAT`, but I encountered cases where the conversion is to `DECMAL(2, 1)` as that is the scale and precision of the scalar constant that you used.  This question is now showing SQL-Server and so instead of `FLOAT`, this will yield `DECIMAL`.